# ReportViewer Version 11.0.0.0. parameter dropdown won't open second time

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I've created an ASP.NET (C#) using Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version 11.0.0.0. If a user selects a parameter multi-select dropdown, then clicks away without selecting an item in the list, the dropdown closes but will not reopen unless the page is refreshed.

This appears to only happen in MS Internet Explorer (testing with IE9). Chrome doesn't appear to have this issue.

Does anyone know of a fix for this, or documentation of a known issue?

Comment: Have you tried with/out compatibility mode turned on?

Comment: You have a dropdown INSIDE your report ?

Answer (score 0):

Root Cause 1 : May be dropdown Z-index low
Root Cause 2 : If your using update panel render mode and update mode need change into always

IE Compadability view may be problem check IE view type